# getUserMedia notallowederror : permission denied

Tags: node.js, permissions, permission-denied

Um...
when i play 'getUserMedia' on my phone, i got an error

> from alert(e)) notallowederror : permission denied

What should i do?

it is a part of the index.js code(where the video & chating happens)...

```
async function getMedia(deviceId) {
  const initialConstraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: { facingMode: 'user' },
  };

  const cameraConstraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: { deviceId: { exact: deviceId } },
  };

  try {
    myStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
      deviceId ? cameraConstraints : initialConstraints
    );
    myFace.srcObject = myStream;

    if (!deviceId) {
      await getCameras();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

I'm using rails app(web), and react-native(webview app), node.js(for realtime chating and video call like zoom by socket.io webRTC)

I ran it on the webview-app(hybrid), and that doesn't working... (working weeeell in browser but..)
so i googling .. add the options..

```
video autoplay="" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" playsinline="playsinline" muted="true" id="myFace" width="350" height="400"
```

and video tag's parent is iframe, and it has attributes allow="camera;microphone;autoplay" and so on...

Also added the expo webview options like,,,

```
return useWebkit
allowInlineMediaPlayback={true}
mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
javaScriptEnabled={true}
javaScriptEnabledAndroid
geolocationEnabled={true}
```

im so beginner.. can you help me out?? THanks!!!

Comment: If the code you are trying to execute `alert(e);` is on your backend, the problem is that you cannot `alert` from node. This is the reason for the `permission denied`

Comment: @LucaPizzini Thanks again!! I deleted `alert(e)` but there's nothing changed..  and it was on the index.js which is not backend. I got another server.js file... I thought the problem cause from react native, webview... googling doesn't gave me an answer.  Anyway so Thanks!!

Comment: I got it...!!!!  it was because of `import {Camera} from 'expo-camera';` this... After add this code, everything works... hahaha......

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error in Localhost or any site, you have to go to settings and search for microphone or webcam and enable/disable it manually,

[image]

[image]